# MySQL Query always returns -1

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
# encoding: utf-8
import sys
import os
import mysql.connector as sql
import json

conn = sql.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, unix_socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", user="root", password="root", database="acrpv")
db = conn.cursor()
print db.execute("SELECT * FROM Posts")
```

I tried to run this code when connected to MySQL server database running under PHPMyAdmin but it always returns -1. A friend of mine told my it could be the connection, but I already tried everything and it keeps returning -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing db.fetchall() after the execute line.

Comment: It gives an error saying that you can't fetch an integer.